# What is the Levi--Civita connection of a Wick rotated metric?

Tags: mathematical-physics, differential-geometry, wick-rotation

A Wick rotation  is a transformation that allows to change from a Lorentzian manifold to a Riemaniann manifold. In the cases when this is possible, is the Levi-Civita connection of the Riemaniann manifold the same connection as the initial Lorentzian manifold?

Comment: Related post by OP: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/789394/11127 Related MO post: http://mathoverflow.net/q/165304/13917